# Comparing strings in C starting at at xth character (C)

Tags: c, string, compare

I'm using the following code to sort an array of strings:

```
char dirarr[MAX][MAX], temp[MAX];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
     if (strcmp(dirarr[j], dirarr[j + 1]) > 0) {
        strcpy(temp, dirarr[j]);
        strcpy(dirarr[j], dirarr[j + 1]);
        strcpy(dirarr[j + 1], temp);
     }
  }
}
```

Now I have the following problem but I didn't find a solution:
I have to sort this array of strings but I have to compare it starting at the sixth character and not at the beginning of each string. I tried a couple things but didn't find a solution that works.
Could you please help me with this?

Thanks Armin

Comment: Are strings of atleast 'x' characters ?

Comment: I defined MAX with 255.

Comment: if the NULL character of string lies after x character, then its simple straight forward comparison starting at from xth index in both string else you need to code extra. Also you can use `qsort` too easily if that's the case

Comment: I also thought that I only have to start from the xth character but my problem is that I don't know how to change my code to realize this. The same with qsort, I didn't entered the correct parameters to run it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {

     // Make sure that there are at least 6 characters in each string.
     if ( strlen(dirarr[j]) > 5 && strlen(dirarr[j + 1]) > 5 )
     {
        // Compare from the 6-th characters
        if (strcmp(dirarr[j]+5, dirarr[j + 1]+5) > 0) {
          strcpy(temp, dirarr[j]);
          strcpy(dirarr[j], dirarr[j + 1]);
          strcpy(dirarr[j + 1], temp);
        }
     }

     // Figure out what do when one of the strings has less than 6 characters
     else
     {
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Why the if check for lengths ? Either assume it, or need to code move to more less than 6 character string to either side of array. This probably won't sort the array if it has mix lengths

Comment: It doesn't make sense to compare the string starting from the 6-th character if the strings are not that long to start with. The policy for what to do when there are less than 6 characters in one of the strings is a different matter. If you skip the first test, you take the risk of accessing out of bounds memory.

Comment: Yeah agreed, but above logic probably won't do any ordering if its has mixed lengths

Comment: @P0W, I see your concern. I added an `else` block in the answer to give the user a hint that they need to deal with the `else` condition.

Comment: This code works perfectly for my application. I am creating an own version of ls and so the length is the same for every string in this array. It doesn't matter if the strings have not exactly the same length. Thank you all for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your strings are at least 6 characters long, the following should work:

```
if (strcmp(dirarr[j]+5, dirarr[j + 1]+5) > 0)
```